# Can't Run PHP 8.3 with Apache 2.4.58 CENTOS 7

Tags: php, apache, centos7, httpd.conf

I'm currently working on upgrading my server, moving from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.3 and from Apache 2.4.6 to Apache 2.4.58. The site loads normally using PHP 7.3. However, when I attempt to use PHP 8.3 and Apache 2.4.58/2.4.6, the site doesn't load, and it seems like Apache is unable to detect the installed PHP.

PHP code is not being executed:

- [PHP ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC6dO.png)
- [PHP ERROR 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxkQe.png)

However, when I configure it as follows:

- PHP 7.3 and Apache 2.4.6, it works
- PHP 7.3 and Apache 2.4.58, it works
- PHP 8.3 and Apache 2.4.6, it doesn't works (Apache can't read PHP)
- PHP 8.3 and Apache 2.4.58 it doesn't works (Apache can't read PHP)

I suspect there might be an issue with PHP 8.3, but I can't identify the specific problem. (I'm unable to pinpoint the exact problem.) Upon further investigation, I found an error in the apache log:

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

I'm seeking clarification on two points:

- If this issue is related to compatibility, which version of Apache is compatible with PHP 8.3? I've searched extensively but haven't found conclusive information.
- If this problem isn't about compatibility, could there be an error in my Apache configuration or with the installed PHP modules?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

For additional context:

1. apache error_log:
   `https://pastebin.com/8JnQyTqV`
2. apache config httpd.conf:
   `https://pastebin.com/TbxLMekb`
3. installed yum module:
   `https://pastebin.com/ePZwZDUZ`
4. /httpd/conf.modules.d/20-php.conf:
   `https://pastebin.com/UbwKpMg8`
5. /httpd/conf.d/php.conf:
   `https://pastebin.com/QAh1iA17`

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Can you share any error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: fyi, you can paste code here on the platform

Comment: Maybe this is an error:  

[Thu Dec 14 15:20:36.834061 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 25404:tid 139893963470592] [client 10.248.140.110:62775] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Hope someone will help him

Comment: @NicoHaase I found this at log: AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm sorry.. I've updated my question, hopefully it's more clear. Thank you very much

Comment: As you haven't shared any configuration so far, it's impossible to provide help. Also, if this is not a programming issue, but a server configuration issue, please move it to serverfault.com

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for the respond, I did share my apache config file and error log, could you please specify which configuration file you're referring to, to clarify this question further? beside those config I shared, the other modules/config should be default setting (fresh installed)

Comment: I didn't find any configuration related to php in your httpd.conf

Comment: @shingo 
Thank you for reminding me about the PHP Apache config. It should be in the 20-php.conf file that I just added.

Comment: Try to remove all the conditions, just load the module.

Comment: Since Centos 7 will be EOL in a few months and there are alternatives available, trying to get a non-repo stack running on it now is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar issue. I tried downgrading Apache then downgrading PHP.
Still had issues executing PHP.

After much searching and trial and error this worked for me.

In httpd.conf, I added the following under the other LoadModule entries:
LoadModule php_module php8apache2_4.dll
PHPIniDir="C:/php"

Then in the MIME section:

<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>

Hope this helps.